# Adjusting some labels in a circuitikz

Tags: labels, circuitikz

The following produces output *very* close to what I would like:

```
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw
        (0,0) to[short,l=2.95 GHz] (0,0)
              to[bandpass,>,l=BPF,a=2.95 GHz] ++(3.5,0)
              node[inputarrow]{}
              node[mixer,anchor=west] (mix) {};
    \draw
        (mix.east) to[lowpass,>,l=LPF,a=100 MHz] ++(3.5,0)
                   node[inputarrow]{ADC};
    \draw (mix.south) node[inputarrow,rotate=90] (loarrow) {} -- ++(0,-1.5)
                      to[short,l=3 GHz] ++(0,0);
\end{circuitikz}
```

The problem is that the text "ADC" is offset a little high, and not symmetric with the "2.95 GHz" text at the input.

Similarly, the "3 GHz" text is offset to the left, instead of centered with respect to its associated arrow.

How can I better align these labels?

Comment: You have labels and arrows on lines of lenght  0 (the `++(0,0)` things) --- TikZ is unable to decide the direction of the line (clearly!) and anything can happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most circuitikz nodes are not designed to handle text.

Note that all labels are actually separate nodes.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw
        (0,0) to[short,l=2.95 GHz] (0,0)
              to[bandpass,>,l=BPF,a=2.95 GHz] ++(3.5,0)
              node[inputarrow]{}
              node[mixer,anchor=west] (mix) {};
    \draw
        (mix.east) to[lowpass,>,l=LPF,a=100 MHz] ++(3.5,0)
                   node[inputarrow]{} node[right]{ADC};
    \draw (mix.south) node[inputarrow,rotate=90] (loarrow) {} -- ++(0,-1.5)
                      node[below]{3 GHz};
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: and the `3GHz` move right

Comment: @jsbibra - Oops,  Fixed now.  BTW, the circuitiz manual assumes you already know how to use TikZ and only shows the new features.

Comment: true that--i feel it easier to do the labeling afterwards--in the initial stage only lay down the components at there coord and assign a variable--the variable is then assigned a label afterwards